# Error with canvas.toDataURL (Image is on the same server)

Tags: django, html, canvas

I'm getting a Security Error while using canvas.toDataURL(). 
The image that I'm drawing is hosted on the same server, so I don't see why that should be happening.

The canvas is on an html file thats part of a larger Django app. Could that have anything to do with it?

Thanks

Comment: What is the URL of the image, and what is the URL of the page with the canvas element?

Comment: The html file is in the Templates folder, and the image is in the MEDIA_ROOT folder.

Comment: OK, what is the URL of the Templates folder and what is the URL of the MEDIA_ROOT folder?

Answer (score 0):

Image should be hosted not only on the same server, but on the same domain.

Comment: It's the same domain. I do not have a thorough understanding of how Django works, but the html file is in the Templates folder, and the image is in the MEDIA_ROOT folder. The domain, protocol etc. are all the same.